# Firefox is rendering window and pages transparent and flickering

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, firefox

On Ubuntu 20.04, I don't know if the problem started when updating Firefox v81 or Nvidea graphic card driver v450.

**Issue:** The Firefox show transparent window and pages random flickering. The desktop and other apps aren't affected. In Preferences tab, I'm using "Recommended Performance Settings" on, but nothing change if set it off.

**One tip:** I opened the black screen of VLC player behind the Firefox window to achieve see something on transparent screen.

Some idea to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem:** Firefox show transparent window when set `gfx.webrender.all` to `true` in `about:config`.

**Solution:** Set it to `false` and restart the browser then all back to normal.

**Source:** [Improve Firefox Performance on Linux by Turning WebRender On](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2020/07/firefox-enable-webrender-linux)

**Explaining:** WebRender is the brand new Mozilla render developed in Rust lang that's replacing the old GECKO render developed in C++. However, it's for experimental use yet.

Comment: Fine. But how to do so whithout seeing anything :'( ? Is there a way to accomplish this from command line ? By modifiying a config file (even a SQLite-based config file) ? Thanks !

Comment: I changed nvidia driver from proprietary to nouveau, and Firefox shows up normally again. But gfx.webrender.all in about:config WAS already set to false ! This is quite weird that only Firefox is concerned...

Comment: @natsirt you can edit your settings here: ~/.mozilla/firefox/xxx.default-release/prefs.js

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here in Linux Mint 20.2.

In NVIDIA X Server settings, switching **Enable FXAA** to *false* in Antialiasing settings solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I just had the same problem on Fedora after upgrading to F34.  All Firefox (v90) windows were rendered using additive transparency making it completely unusable.  Turns out I had to delete `~/.nvidia-settings-rc` and Firefox went back to normal after logging out and logging back in.

Comment: Maybe Nvidea 470 driver recent update... there are several issues reported on login screen, Chrome, HDMI audio, etc.

https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/c/gpu-graphics/linux/148